# Beamer: qed symbol when split a frame into multi-pages

Tags: beamer, proof-package

I would like to split a frame consisting of a proof environment into 2 pages.
I find that it works well when the proof is organized by an `itemize` environment.
See the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<only@1> part~1.
      \item<only@2> part~2.
        \qedhere
    \end{itemize}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second page contains a qed symbol, while the first page does not.
[image]
[image]
BTW, the second block is slightly higher than the first one.

But it fails without using `itemize`.
See the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proof}
    \only<1>{part~1.}
    \only<2>{part~2.}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The first page contains also a qed symbol.
[image]

Is there some way to avoid this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that `\only<>{...}` only removes the part encompassed by the braces while the end of the proof will still be part of the first slide. A quick workaround is to use `\pause`. Another possibility would be using open-ended macros like `\onslide` etc.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{proof}
    part~1.
    \pause
    part~2.
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Since I hope the contents `part~1` to only appear in the first slide, it should be included in `\only<1>{...}`. That is, `\only<1>{part~1.} \pause part~2.`

Comment: BTW, I wonder why there is no problem when using `itemize` environment as in my first example. Could you provide some idea?

Comment: @jiaopjie the `only@...` in the itemize environment is a bit different than `\only`. It is more like an open ended `onlyenv` environment

Comment: If the first slide is ended with a display math, there will be an extra blank line. Such as `\begin{proof} \only<1>{part~1\[f(x)\]} \pause \only<2>{part~2} \end{proof}`. Is there some way to avoid the blank line, other than using a negative vspace?

Comment: A negative space is probably easiest